# PHPWord Footer Position

Tags: position, footer, margins, phpword, phpoffice

Does anyone know if it is possible to re-position (or set the height of) a footer using PHPWord?

I have a footer exactly as required in terms of text.

```
$footer = $section->addFooter();
$textrun = $footer->addTextRun();
$textrun->addText('My Footer Text');
```

However, what I'd like to achieve is to:

Reduce the height of the footer or set the distance from bottom of the page.

[image: Space I'd like to remove]

There in an option in Word365 called "Footer from bottom", there are also similar options in older versions of Word.

[image: Option in Word365]

I've tried adjusting the page margins but these appear to be separate from the footer (and header) positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by reviewing the GitHub repo.

This commit provides a solution: [Added support for page header & page footer height](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/commit/d1e16a66d658dec061b0805ce09092e4d930ef68)

You can pass the attributes "headerHeight" & "footerHeight" when you create the section that contains your header and footer.

```
// Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section = $this->_phpWord->addSection(array(
                        'headerHeight' => 300,
                        'footerHeight' => 50)
                    );

$footer = $section->addFooter();
$textrun = $footer->addTextRun();
$textrun->addText('My Footer Text');
```

There are also some public methods for setting these values after you've created your section, these are: setFooterHeight() and setHeaderHeight().

```
$section->setHeaderHeight(300);
$section->setFooterHeight(50);
```

Comment: Setting the values as parameters in addSection() works.
Setting header/footer heights later does not work if parameters (of any kind) have already been specified in addSection.  
– PHPWord v0.16.0 (30 dec 2018) –